# Python 3 Import Text File with Floating Point Numbers and Mixed Content

Tags: python, numpy

I have as section of code that inputs:

```
LOEWDIN ATOMIC CHARGES
----------------------
   0 C :   -0.780631
   1 H :    0.114577
   2 Br:    0.309802
   3 Cl:    0.357316
   4 F :   -0.001065
```

And this is the code:

```
import numpy as np


name = input("Enter Molecule ID: ")

name_in = name+'.lac.dat'
print(name_in)

atm_chg = []

with open(name_in) as f:
    # skip two lines
    f.readline()
    f.readline()
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line.strip(): # is the line non-empty, ignoring white space
            atm_chg.append(float( line.split()[-1] ))

np.savetxt('atm_chg',atm_chg,delimiter=',')
```

The above produces:

```
-7.806309999999999638e-01
1.145769999999999983e-01
3.098020000000000218e-01
3.573160000000000225e-01
-1.064999999999999974e-03
```

I want to do the same thing with this text file:

```
                      * MAYER POPULATION ANALYSIS *
                      *****************************

  NA   - Mulliken gross atomic population
  ZA   - Total nuclear charge
  QA   - Mulliken gross atomic charge
  VA   - Mayer's total valence
  BVA  - Mayer's bonded valence
  FA   - Mayer's free valence

  ATOM       NA         ZA         QA         VA         BVA        FA
  0 C      5.8816     6.0000     0.1184     4.2631     4.2631     0.0000
  1 H      0.8495     1.0000     0.1505     0.9510     0.9510     0.0000
  2 Br    35.0064    35.0000    -0.0064     1.2192     1.2192    -0.0000
  3 Cl    17.0401    17.0000    -0.0401     1.2405     1.2405    -0.0000
  4 F      9.2225     9.0000    -0.2225     1.0449     1.0449    -0.0000
```

So far everything that I've tried has failed, and I really don't what to try next.

I would appreciate a shove in the right direction.

Comment: Read the line.  Split the line. You've now got an array of floating points (after line number and atomic symbol)

Comment: `np.genfromtxt` can read that file into an array.  You'll need to skip header lines.  If you just want to load the float columns select columns.  Otherwise be prepared to load a structured array with fields containing strings and floats.  `savetxt` will be simpler if you just work with the floats.

Comment: Many thanks. np.genfromtxt worked!